# Iterating a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Incredibly simple question, but I think I'm unable to come up with the correct terminology to google search it.

If I have a snippet of code that relies on three independent variables:

```
code(x,y,z)
```

That produces two values, i.e.:

```
output1, output2
```

How do I go about iterating like so (pseudocode):

```
for x

    for y

        for z

            code(x,y,z)

        end

    end

end
```

And have data I can parse to generate 3D graphs such as

```
surf(x,y,output1)
```

A naive solution I came up with was just to create a bin of *n* length and then iterating one variable *n* times to come up with a 2D graph, i.e:

```
x_axis = zeros(1,25)

for m = 1:25

    xm = x + 1
    x_axis(m) = xm

    code(x,y,z)
```

Even a referral to some documentation would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Brute force approach:

```
for x=[1:50]
    for y=[1:50]
        for z=[1:50]
            result(y,x,z)=code(x,y,z);
        end
    end
end
```

More paradigmatic approach (in MATLAB) is to `meshgrid` it, and pump those in.

```
[XX,YY,ZZ]=meshgrid([1:50],[1:50],[1:50]);
result=code(XX,YY,ZZ);
```

Comment: How can you retrieve the outputs generated from this method and inject them into a graph?

Comment: You shouldn't use `[]` around `1:50` as this will first generate the array `1:50` and then make an array (the same) out of that, which is unnecessary, and (marginally) slower. If you want to make sure that calculation is made correctly use standard brackets `()`.